# How to add a telephone number in cart gift option form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, giftmessage

As per my head line is there any way to add a telephone number in gift option form on the cart page. I have added the image for best explanation.
[image]

Comment: Is your Magento version be enterprise edition?

Comment: no.its Community edition

Comment: Can you show me where is the config for this feature?